# Variable's value doesn't increment within nested loops (File writing with Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops, file-writing

I have a code to parse through several text files and extract a given part from each one and write them into another text file. I repeat this process over and over again, extracting the next part of the files and writing them on the other text file.

I'm using the variable `cube_i` to move from one file to another and the variable `layer` to move from one part of the text files to another. However, the loops I created don't go further than the `cube_i=0` and `layer=0`. Any suggestions on how I can proceed to increment the value of those variables?

```
rgx_start = re.compile(r'Z down')  # Second line before the start of the layer code: "G0Z2 ; Z down"
rgx_end = re.compile(r'Layer #')  # Second line after the end of the layer code: "; Layer #<integer>"
if layer in range(0, (layers_total + 1)):
    final_code.write('; ------------------------------\n')
    label = ';          Layer #{}\n'.format(layer)
    final_code.write(label)
    final_code.write('; ------------------------------\n')
    with open(first_file,'r') as gcode:  # Opening the first file to write the powder drop
        for i, line in enumerate(gcode.readlines()):
            if i in range(powdrop_start, (powdrop_end + 1)):  # Writing the powder drop
                final_code.write(line)
    cube_i = 0 # Reseting the cube_i variable
    if cube_i in range(0, (parts_total + 1)):
        label_cube = ';   PART #{}\n'.format(cube_i)
        final_code.write(label_cube)
        # Opening each text file separately
        with open(f_path, 'r') as gcode:  # f_path contains cube_i
            lines = gcode.readlines()
        start_i = prev_start[cube_i]
        for i, line in enumerate(lines[start_i + 1:]):  # Searching for the beginning of given layer
            if rgx_start.search(line):
                layer_start = start_i + i + 3
                break
        for i, line in enumerate(lines[layer_start + 1:]):  # Searching for the end of given layer
            if rgx_end.search(line):
                layer_end = layer_start + i - 1
                break
        for i, line in enumerate(lines[layer_start:layer_end + 1]):
            final_code.write(line)
        prev_start.append(layer_start)
        prev_end.append(layer_end)
        cube_i = + 1
    if layer == 0: # Writing the zeroth layer footer
        with open(first_file, 'r') as gcode:
            for i, line in enumerate(gcode.readlines()):
                if i == zeroth_ftr:
                    final_code.write(line)
    layer =+ 1
```

Comment: You don't have any nested loops. Is `if layer in range(...)` supposed to be `for layer in range(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of for loops in the code which have been incorrectly written as if statements. 
The correct code snipped would be :

```
rgx_start = re.compile(r'Z down')  # Second line before the start of the layer code: "G0Z2 ; Z down"
rgx_end = re.compile(r'Layer #')  # Second line after the end of the layer code: "; Layer #<integer>"
for layer in range(0, (layers_total + 1)):
    final_code.write('; ------------------------------\n')
    label = ';          Layer #{}\n'.format(layer)
    final_code.write(label)
    final_code.write('; ------------------------------\n')
    with open(first_file,'r') as gcode:  # Opening the first file to write the powder drop
        for i, line in enumerate(gcode.readlines()):
            if i in range(powdrop_start, (powdrop_end + 1)):  # Writing the powder drop
                final_code.write(line)
    cube_i = 0 # Reseting the cube_i variable
    for cube_i in range(0, (parts_total + 1)):
        label_cube = ';   PART #{}\n'.format(cube_i)
        final_code.write(label_cube)
        # Opening each text file separately
        with open(f_path, 'r') as gcode:  # f_path contains cube_i
            lines = gcode.readlines()
        start_i = prev_start[cube_i]
        for i, line in enumerate(lines[start_i + 1:]):  # Searching for the beginning of given layer
            if rgx_start.search(line):
                layer_start = start_i + i + 3
                break
        for i, line in enumerate(lines[layer_start + 1:]):  # Searching for the end of given layer
            if rgx_end.search(line):
                layer_end = layer_start + i - 1
                break
        for i, line in enumerate(lines[layer_start:layer_end + 1]):
            final_code.write(line)
        prev_start.append(layer_start)
        prev_end.append(layer_end)
        cube_i = + 1
    if layer == 0: # Writing the zeroth layer footer
        with open(first_file, 'r') as gcode:
            for i, line in enumerate(gcode.readlines()):
                if i == zeroth_ftr:
                    final_code.write(line)
    layer =+ 1
```

This should work in your case.